# The operator != is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean, int - glfwInit()

Tags: java, lwjgl, glfw

I have started a game loop and I am struggling with the GLFW window, I am checking if glfwInit != GL_TRUE however I get the error in the title. 
Here is the code, if anyone could explain this to me i'd appreciate it

```
package com.crim.bts;

import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.*;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWVidMode;

public class Main implements Runnable{
    Thread thread;
    public boolean running = true;

    public static void Main(String args[]){
        Main game = new Main();
        game.start();
    }
    public void start(){
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this, "Beneath The Surface");
        thread.start();
    }

    public void init(){
        if(glfwInit() != GL_TRUE){
            System.err.println("GLFW initialization failed!");
        }

        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_TRUE);
    }

    public void update(){

    }

    public void render(){

    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        init();
        while(running){
            update();
            render();
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Where is `glfwInit()` defined?  And likewise for `GL_TRUE`.  Nevermind, I found documentation that `glfwInit()` returns an `int`.  I would guess that `GL_TRUE` is a `boolean`, in which case you are comparing an `int` to a `boolean` which isn't allowed in Java, like the error says.

Comment: `!=` doesn't make sense when comparing a boolean with an int, because the two will never be equal.

Comment: Ahhhh that makes sense!

Answer (score 2):

[GL_TRUE](https://javadoc.lwjgl.org/constant-values.html#org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_TRUE) is an int with the value 1.

[glfwInit()](https://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/glfw/GLFW.html#glfwInit--) returns an boolean

Replace it with:

```
    if(!glfwInit()){
        System.err.println("GLFW initialization failed!");
    }
```

You can't compare an int with a boolean.

Comment: You can't directly compare unrelated types generally, except with `equals` which returns `false` for instances of different types (except in pathological implementations).